# How do I automatically fill LaTeX templates with from a table of data?

Tags: templates, automation, scripts

I have a LaTeX template like

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, \VAR{USER}!
\end{document}
```

and a table of users (for example as a csv) like

```
ID,USER
01,Peter
02,Michael
03,Jana
...
```

How can I generate pdf files hello_01.pdf, hello_02.pdf, hello_03.pdf, ... with the content being the latex document filled with the usernames? So hello_01.pdf just contains "Hello, Peter!".

Is there some application that automatically fills and compiles the pdf files for me or do I have to write something from scratch, and how would I begin doing that?

Comment: One latex run generates one PDF file. So you need a script to run latex multiple times.
Or generate multiple pages and then use a PDF splitter program to split it into multiple PDF files.

Comment: I don't care about the runtime of such a script, as long as I don't need to do it manually so running latex multiple times is okay. But how do I generate the latex files initially?

Comment: I would use what ever programming language you are comfortable with to read the csv, and generate the many latex files. Then a tool like `latexmk -pdf *.tex` can run latex on all the generated `.tex` files and convert them to PDF. I think it would be overkill til attempt to solve this purely from latex it selv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Python script to do it. It just replaces the `\VAR{USER}` text with the USER field from the row, and writes it to a file `hello_ID.tex` and then processes that file with `latexmk`. Run with the command `python process.py`, or if you are on Windows, probably `py process.py`.

Of course it could be generalised to use more variables, for example using some string-template library, but I wanted to keep it simple.

File: template.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, \VAR{USER}!
\end{document}
```

File: input.csv

```
ID,USER
01,Peter
02,Michael
03,Jana
```

File: process.py

```
import csv
import subprocess

def generate_file(template, id, user):
    filename = f'hello_{id}.tex'
    with open(filename, 'w') as latex_file:
        latex = template.replace(r'\VAR{USER}', user)
        latex_file.write(latex)
    print(f'Generated {filename}')
    subprocess.call(['latexmk', '-pdf', filename])

with open('template.tex') as template_file:
    global latex_code
    latex_code = template_file.read()
    print (latex_code)

with open('input.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            generate_file(latex_code, row[0], row[1])
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Comment: Nicely done! :)

Comment: Very clean solution, thank you :)